# Conditionals (Past Tense)

Tags: conditionals, conditional-perfect

In terms of conditional sentences, is it correct to say:

- if you knew why I WAS here, then I wouldn't need to be here.

or

- If you knew why I WERE here, then I wouldn't need to be here.

Which type of conditional is this? Type 2?
I was thought at school that there are three types of conditionals. Are there more of them?

Comment: The second one is only reasonable if you are not in fact "here" when you say it. It's a counterfactual, like _If I were you_ --since I am by definition not you, this is against fact, or "counterfactual". And it doesn't make any sense with the _then_ clause, which assumes you **are** here.

Comment: I am sorry to be the one to inform you that the entire “numbered conditionals” nonsense you were taught was a facile lie that has little bearing on English as it is actually spoken.

Comment: Your question is interesting, imo. :) . . . It seems that you're trying to put your sentence in the form of a remote conditional construction, due to the use of the verbs "knew" and "wouldn't" which are past-tense verbs (preterite). The verbs you have put it all capitals ("WAS" and "WERE") are in subordinate clauses, and might supposedly be there to be used as backshift preterites. But the irrealis "were" supposedly shouldn't be used as a backshift preterite; though some speakers do extend the use of the irrealis "were" in that way for some type of sentences.

Comment: Why do people here place answers in comments?

Answer (score 3):

The subordinate clause *why I was here* refers to a matter which lies outside the temporal/modal framework of the conditional construction. Presumably both parties accept as a fact that I **was** here at some past time, so it cannot be included in the present-referent irrealis domain established by *knew* and *would*.

As for the three (or four, or five, or however many) conditionals, that is nothing but a 'baby rule' employed as a pedagogic tool to get you involved in conditional constructions; as tchrist says, it has nothing to do with the facts on the ground, and should be discarded now that your fluency has carried you beyond it.

Declerck and Reed, *Conditionals: A Comprehensive Empirical Analysis* (de Gruyter: 2001), classifying conditionals along syntactic, semantic and pragmatic axes, distinguish several score different types; they show that in the proper context it is possible to construct an acceptable conditional with **any** combination of tenses, aspects and modalities in the two clauses; and they remark specifically of what they call the ‘three canonical tense patterns’ that

> There are at least three dozen ways in which conditionals of these three tense patterns (taken together) can be interpreted.

Stoutly abjure the trinity.