# "If you knew what the future" held/holds?

Tags: grammar

So, I was listening to Katy Perry's *Firework*, and she sings

> If you only knew what the future holds...

My problem with this is that I think that her usage of "knew" means that she should sing

> If you only knew what the future held...

instead. Searching the internet shows me that "knew what the future held" is correct, but I can't argue that "holds" doesn't work because the future hasn't occurred yet. I have also not seen anything against the usage of "holds" in this sentence.

Is this sentence idiomatic, or is it just "artistic license: grammar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Knew* is in the past subjunctive, because it expresses a counterfactual statement: The person does in fact *not* know what the future holds. So even though it appears to be a past tense, it actually does not depict time at all. Therefore *holds* is correct.

EDIT: *Held* could also work, depending on whether they speak about the past.

Comment: So, it depends on the context? I interpreted the sentence in the way you pointed out in your edit. So, if she were talking about the _present_, then "holds" would be right?

Comment: Exactly. The past subjunctive can even be about statements in the future. For instance: “If I were in Paris tomorrow, I would visit the Eiffel Tower.” It is in the past subjunctive, because it is counterfactual: I will not be in Paris tomorrow.

Comment: One more thing, would this sentence make sense: "If you knew what the future held for you, you wouldn't do that."? It sounds right to me, but applying your rule it should be "If you knew what the future holds for you, you wouldn't do that." should be correct (and also sounds right to me). Is this just a case of the subjunctive being phased out, or something else (or context, again)?

Comment: The first one is about the past, so I would say: “If you knew what the future held for you, you would not have done that.” (The entire thing occurred in the past). The second one happens in the present, so that is correct as it is. I think the problem is mostly that the past subjunctive almost always coincides with the past simple. (Though you may hear people say “If I was you” rather than “If I were you”; the former being the past simple (incorrect), the latter the past subjunctive (correct).)

Comment: Ah, OK. The lyrics, by the way, seem to point to the present (and hence, I suppose, my confusion).

Comment: The ‘past’ part of the past subjunctive is indeed kind of misleading.

Comment: Precisely. [The subordinate clause (*what the future holds/held* in this case) refers to a matter which lies outside the temporal/modal framework of the conditional construction,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/186953/2637) from an answer to an earlier question in the same general area.

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely not idiomatic:  an idiom's meaning **cannot be guessed from the words alone, and requires prior knowledge of the idiom**.  If she had mentioned "looking into a crystal ball" then **that** would be idiomatic, as on the face of it it makes no sense - it requires you to know that in some fairy tales a crystal ball is used to see the future.  Simple grammatical errors are not idioms.

This is of course an example of artistic licence, and in fact might be an example of deliberate dumbing down to speak to her audience of mainly teenagers (to be honest, it's not dumbing down that much as I think this is a mistake that many educated people would also make).

EDIT:  I'm half-expecting someone to come along and point out that it's not even grammatically incorrect...

Comment: The primary sense in which 'idiomatic' is used does not mean 'pertaining to idioms'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you're right, thanks - i'd always taken it to mean its secondary definition.